# How to take the executable file of the particular software and install in other system?

Tags: installation, unity

How to take the executable file of the particular software and install in other system like we tacking back up in android applications

Comment: Can you expand your question, please. What exactly you want to be taken? Executables not need to be installed, they only need their environment to be executed properly.

Comment: take an example  Eclipse.I have it in my pc but i want to install the software in my lap how can i done it

Comment: You can just download it from [official site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), and export your settings and projects, if you worried about them. Or I do not understand you? Why do you want to take it?

Comment: i have no net connection

Comment: What operation system is installed on both computers?

Comment: same ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Generally eclipse is portable, that means that it can be just copied to another computer with the same OS, because binaries usually OS specific. I expand my answer

Comment: this should help: [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 0):

**This answer helps if you only need to move eclipse to another computer, with same OS, which is Ubuntu**

**There is a better generous solution in comments, given by user [hash](https://askubuntu.com/users/212123/hash).**

First of all you should find where exactly you eclipse installation folder is. Usually it is `/usr/lib/eclipse`. You can put it in tar `sudo tar -pcvzf eclipse.tar.gz /usr/lib/eclipse`, and copy to your another computer.

Then do this line by line on computer where you want to copy:

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo mkdir eclipse && cd eclipse
sudo tar -pxvzf /path_to_tar/eclipse.tar.gz
```

Then you should create symlink in `/usr/local/bin/` to execute eclipse.
Create a file named `eclipse` in `/usr/local/bin/`, fill it with this:

```
#!/bin/sh

ECLIPSE=/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
if [ ! -d ~/.eclipse/ ] ; then
    $ECLIPSE -clean -initialize || exit $?
fi

exec $ECLIPSE "$@"
```

Give execute permission to this file:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/eclipse
```

Now you should be able to run eclipse from terminal using eclipse command:

```
eclipse
```